# Is there a way to NOT have the REACT_APP_ env vars prefix?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I was unable to get env vars to work in a create react app until I read this: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Is there any way to avoid having to prefix all the env vars with `REACT_APP_`?

I'm doing it now, just to get it to work. But it is pretty silly to have env vars like `REACT_APP_SERVER_URL`

Comment: "But it is pretty silly to have env vars like..."  the article that you posted very clearly states the reason for that naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

With dotenv, you can easily add environment variables to your project without such prefix.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();
```